# codeigniter how i can load two diffrent mysql table list in single view

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I want to develop a edit form for newsletter. I have done this but i can't load category list in same view.

if user click on newsletter its open in edit view, in this edit view i want to give him a option for category selection option. categories are stored in different table name cat.

i have tried it but its showing only one category.

Please help me am new in Php

Answer (score 1):

Well, without any actual code examples, this is going to de pretty tough... Presumably the edit view is a form, and you are using the form helper to generate a dropdown field.

The first thing you need are the categories in the right format to be displayed in the dropdown.

From the [CodeIgniter docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) :

```
$options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );
```

where the array keys are your options values and the array values are the text displayed.

You need to get your categories in this format with your model. I tend to use the id as the option value, so you could have a function like this in your model:

```
function get_cat(){
  $q=$this->db->get('cat');
  if ($q->num_rows()>=1){
    foreach($q->result() as $row){
      $data[$row->id]=$row->name;
    }
    return $data
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

and assuming your controller passes the result of that function to the view, you can just do this in your view :

```
echo form_dropdown('categories', $data);
```

As a closing note, you might want to start on PHP by developping some things from scratch, not using a framework, you should learn a lot more that way. Just my opinion.

Comment: thanks you jfoucher, you are right i have to learn first PHP then use any Framework

Comment: Can you suggest me a book for php